# What is the maximum amount of data that a node can send to a client?

Tags: solidity, gas, evm

Here is a simple smart contract, with a `bytes32` array called `items` in storage.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SmartContract {

    bytes32[] public items;

    function addItem(bytes32 item) external {
        items.push(item);
    }

    function getAllItems() external view returns(bytes32[] memory) {
        return items;
    }

}
```

I wonder what's the actual **maximum amount of data** that an Ethereum node is willing **to send back to a web client.** Another way to ask this is, how large can the `items` array be before the `getAllItems()` function starts to fail.

1GB, 10GB, 100GB ?

Is that up to the node ? If so, what's the average configuration?

I believe knowing what the theoretical limit is would allow me to create a function that would retrieve only the right maximum amount of data.

I wasn't able to find a correct answer for previous questions on this topic.

- [Is there a gas limit for view requests?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58566/is-there-a-gas-limit-for-view-requests/58568)
- [Gas consumption of a view public function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47033/gas-consumption-of-a-view-public-function)

---